# Read service name from AndroidManifest

Tags: android, android-service, android-manifest

I want to write Firebase's `InstanceId service` like `service` in my project. The project is an `SDK` where the developer who integrates it has the provision to override this `service`. In this case, I should be able to read the name of the new service specified by the developer with a particular action in their `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

So the real question here is, how can I read the name of the service declared in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file with a specific action?

Comment: You need name only? In String format?

Comment: The use-case is to find and start that new service registered by the developer. So a fully qualified name would do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below utility method

```
public static void startService(Context context, String lookupAction) {

        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent();
        serviceIntent.setAction(lookupAction);
        serviceIntent.setPackage("package.of.your.application");

        List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentServices(serviceIntent, 0);
        if (resInfo != null && !resInfo.isEmpty()) {

            ServiceInfo service = resInfo.get(0).serviceInfo;
            ComponentName cmpService = new ComponentName(service.applicationInfo.packageName, service.name);

            Intent serviceToStart = new Intent(lookupAction);

            serviceToStart.setComponent(cmpService);

            context.startService(serviceToStart);
        } else {
            // Handle error
        }
    }
```

I will add documentation soon